# Boost.Program_options: Forward parameters after '--' to another program

Tags: c++, boost, getopt, boost-program-options

I'm writing a C++ application *A* that calls another application *B* in the background. Some command line options are for application *A*, but some should be forwarded to *B*. Separation should work with a double dash `--`.

For example:

```
./my_executable_A -a --long_b some_file -- -c --long_d
```

should parse `{"-a", "--long_b", "some_file"}` in application *A* and forward `{"-c", "--long_d"}` to application *B* when it is called by *A*.

I thought it might make sense to use `boost::program_options` for the task, but I didn't find this functionality. Is this possible?

**Note:** The use case is a `libfuse` file system where some of the options are to be forwarded to the `fuse_main()` function.

Comment: It was some time ago that I messed around with the Boost program options library, but I seem to remember there was a flag or something to ask the library to stop parse when it hit `"--"`, and leave the remaining arguments in `argc`/`argv`.

Comment: You may want to review this ticket in Boost's bug tracker: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6991 - also consider if you are at all willing to modify your command line syntax, or if it is completely set in stone?

Comment: If there is another short syntax, I'd be willing to switch to it. The advantage of this one is that it is used by other libfuse filesystems and therefore known. However, they do manual parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in support for that. What I'd recommend is just create an std::vector out of entire argv array, find "--" and if found, slice the vector and pass first part to program_options (which accepts std::vector too) and the second part to your program.

Answer (score 5):

This is the default behavior (if undocumented) and has been since at least Boost 1.33; [`--` is considered a "terminator"](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/blob/5a85b81fcfbd2e3b6ea0522885128a1ccf1d354b/src/cmdline.cpp#L670) and all command line parameters after it can be accessed as [positional options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp308857536):

```
bool a = false, b = false;
std::vector<std::string> command;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
        ("long_a,a", po::bool_switch(&a), "a")
        ("long_b,b", po::bool_switch(&b), "b")
        ("command", po::value(&command));
po::positional_options_description p;
p.add("command", -1);
po::variables_map vm;
po::parsed_options parsed = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).positional(p).run();
po::store(parsed, vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

Comment: This works, but "usage" prints `--command arg`. How to improve that?

Answer (score 1):

One option you would have is to have them all come in as arguments and after the '--' have those arguments stored in another char** that is sent to a forked process.  Note that before the fork, you would want to set up the outputs and inputs so that they can talk to one another, depending on what you want Application B to do